# How to get json data from asp.net c# return in success function?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, json, extjs

I can't get json data in this code. someone help me plz. . .

Js Code

```
success: function (response) 
{
    var obj;
    try 
    {
        obj = Ext.JSON.decode(response.response.Text);
    } 
    catch (error) { alert(error); }
    this.up('form').getForm().reset();
    Ext.Msg.alert('Success', 'inserted ID: ' + obj.id); <<< I can't get json data 
}
```

simple asp.net c# code

```
var keyValues = new System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, string>
{
     { "success", "true" },
     { "id", 'id'}
};

Response.Write(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(keyValues)); <<< return json object
Response.End();
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: is it hitting the `success` callback or error?

Comment: Show the actual AJAX call, you could be requesting wrong (like cross-domain) etc.

Answer (score 0):

`obj = Ext.JSON.decode(response.responseText);` worked for me, but your code contains an extra dot (.), 
you are using `obj = Ext.JSON.decode(response.response.Text);`

also its not necessary to write `Ext.JSON.decode`, you can use `Ext.decode`